# Add restriction to content on the basis of various User

Tags: hooks

I am new in drupal, So I want to know how can I restrict my content in content listing according to various users. e.g. I have four contents named A,B,C,D. Now I want Customer1 to see and edit only content A and B. While Customer2 can do the same with C and D only.
I've done my research and read about "form_node_admin_content_alter" but not sure how it works. So kindly provide me an efficient solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Creat role and assign role to the different user. Based on role set permissions of view content under people permission page.

If A role user can see A type of content so you can allow permission to view that content type page.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding. Actually I can restrict content on role basis but it will do for the whole content not for particular ones. What I want is user can see the content list but should be able to only see particular content in the list.Please help me if there is a way to do so. thank you once again